# How to validate dataSource name and PortNumber in Connection String of SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlconnection.close

Please tell how to validate dataSource name and PortNumber in Connection String of SqlConnection. Connection state changes to Open, even I donot give any value for dataSource. Like the code below..

```
var Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Trusted_Connection=True");
try
{
    Connection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Succeeded");
}
```

My requirement is I need to validate the Data Source name and Port Number that are entered by EndUser.

Comment: If no data source and port number is defined then an SQLException is thrown at Connection.Open, so do you want to validate connection string before opening connection

Answer (score 1):

**For offline validation**, use SqlConnectionStringBuilder to parse it...

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder myconBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
myconBuilder.ConnectionString = "Data Source=;Trusted_Connection=True";  //Throws exception if garbage connection string like 'abcd' is supplied
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myconBuilder.DataSource))
{ 
    //Throw exception that data source specified is blank 
}
```